# unlink() doesn't work with double backslashes

Tags: php, delete-file, backslash

I'm trying to delete a file this way:

```
define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','c:\temp\\');  
unlink(DESTINATION_FOLDER.$dest_filename);
```

And $dest_filename is something like this: `2jfioj23488hgh83hr.zip`

But this doesn't work. When I put the path in a variable and echo it, it prints:

```
c:\temp\2jfioj23488hgh83hr.zip
```

Then I copy/paste it in unlink():

```
unlink('c:\temp\2jfioj23488hgh83hr.zip')
```

And it works. I think the problem is with the double backslashes. But how should I define the path without using the double backslashes? I don't know why it doesn't work. The line just above this code is:

```
copy((DESTINATION_FOLDER.$dest_filename),($extract.'\\'.$dest_filename));
```

And it works fine, but unlink doesn't work with the same syntax.

Comment: I haven't had much experience writing PHP on a windows server... What exactly is the purpose of the double backslash in the path?  You seem to be manually adding it in your `define` statement - I assume it has some other meaning?

Comment: If it works with single backslashes, why are you trying double backslashes in the first place?

Comment: if i add one backslash before a single qoute it, php scapes the single qoute.

Comment: And if you leave out all the slashes?  You can add them back when concatenating the path... `define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','c:\temp');`

Comment: What server is this running on? I use Wamp on my local windows machine and I can use forward slashes for directory paths thus dodging this issue completely... Wamp uses Apache server

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Now does it work or does it not work with the single backslash contained in the path ? I'd say it should and it is clear why there is a single and not a double backslash. So where is the problem ?

Comment: i didn't even tried forward slashes. they work, thanks Dale

Comment: I'm guessing your using xampp, wamp or some other local http server on your computer as a test server for something you may eventually put on an online hosting server. If this is the case then you should know this. Most online servers supporting php use linux as the os, therefore, this file path will not work. So I would suggest defining your server root in a constant, using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], and/or using relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer to the question

Try using forward slashes instead of backslash :)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you must use backslashes, then you need to use `c:\\` instead of `c:\`

`define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','c:\\temp\\');`